# If $f(n) = \mathcal O(g(n))$ then is $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))?$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

> If $f(n) = \mathcal O(g(n))$ then is $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))?$
>
> My attempt:

$\exists n_0 : \forall n\geq n_0, \exists c>0: f(n)<cg(n) $

Now for large large n, if we take (c/(some integer))*g(n), its graph lies below f(n) {cf(n) (c>1>d>0) more f(n) towards y axis and df(n) takes f(n) away from y-axis }. For sufficiently large n, we can find reasonable c >>0(defenetely not small c for lower bound). So $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))?$

Can any 1 please tell me is this proof correct?

> Another condition: If $f(n) = \mathcal O(g(n))$ and if **$f(n) \neq \Omega(g(n)) $**then is $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))?$

No right? please correct me if i am wrong.

can we take f(n) to be discontinuous function with f(n) = 0 when n is even and f(n) = 1 when n is odd then g(n)=1 is only the upper limit.

> Does $\Omega$ or $\omega$ (asymtotically tight lower bound or asymtotically loose lower bound) mean that can we take smaller c ($c \to 0$) for lower bound? No right? If so how large must be c?

Comment: By definition, $f(n) = \Theta(g(n)) \iff f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $ f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$.

Comment: sir $\mathcal O$  means we have upper bound for f(n). we have no info regarding lower bound. Then how can we say $\mathcal O \implies \Omega$

Comment: I never claimed that and in fact that implication is false. I just edited my comment maybe this clarifies?

Comment: The point is that you can come up with an example where $f(n) = O(g(n))$ but $f(n) \neq \Omega(g(n))$. Take $f(n) = n, g(n) = 2^n$ for example.

Comment: Sir for ex, if we have some say (n= f(n)) =$\mathcal O(n^2)$ then n can be sandwitched between 2n and 0.5n so for any f(n), it can be sandwitched between 2f(n) and 0.5f(n) if n is sufficiently large.

Comment: If you want to prove $f(n) = \Omega(n^2)$ from knowing $f(n) = O(n^2)$, you need to show that there exists $c$ such that for sufficient large $n$, $f(n) \geq cn^2$. You won't be able to prove this though because it's false. What you have shown above is that $f(n) = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: understood sir. THank you.